# How can I initialize a link from all text in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, hyperlink

- I have **only one input** (type=text), in this input someone will type his text and he can paste a link in this field also.
- What I should to do? I should initialize this link in text for beautiful link preview(for this I'll use link-preview-js).
- So, please, help me to initialize a link
- Using: *react, reactTS*

**Input:**

> *The URL() constructor returns a newly created URL object representing the URL defined by the parameters. If the given base URL or the resulting URL are not valid URLs, the JavaScript TypeError exception is thrown.*
> **[www.gfokgfkl.com](http://www.gfokgfkl.com)** (and preview under)

Expect some methods or special type like File -> FileReader for(for  ex) images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a regex. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/12787804) has a good regex to match links. And then you can use [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to extract the link from your input.